# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBaseAxis')

Tags: javascript

I am having the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBaseAxis')` , when trying to create the inside datazoom efect of chart js

This is the code that i have written ,but when i try to scroll it causing the error, I m not sure of other chart configuration are causing the error or what. How can i debug this.
I have multiple charts but only this has the zoom effect feature

```
window.horizontalBarChart = (config) => {
    function number_format_short(number) {
        let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            minimumFractionDigits: 0,
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
            notation: 'compact',
            compactDisplay: 'short'
        });
        let formattedNumber = formatter.format(number);

        return formattedNumber;
    }

    return {
        chart: null,
        init() {
            console.log('Initializing chart...');
            this.chart = echarts.init(config.element);
            console.log('Chart instance:', this.chart);
            this.chart.setOption(this.option());
            console.log('Option set successfully.');
            this.chart.on('click', this.onHorizontalClick.bind(this));
            console.log('Click event listener added.');
        },

        onHorizontalClick(params) {

            if (params.componentType === 'series' && params.seriesType === 'bar') {
                const workflowValue = params.data.data['workflow'];


                const workflowUrl = workflowValue ? `/performances/${workflowValue}/` : '/performances/';

                const route = workflowUrl + params.data.data['stage_name'] + '/tasks';

                const parameters =
                    params.data.data;

                const queryString = objectToQueryString(parameters);

                const url = `${route}?${queryString}`;

                window.open(url, '_blank');
            }
        },
        option() {
            return {
                grid: {
                    show: false, bottom: '0', top: '10', left: '0', right: '15', containLabel: true,
                },
                xAxis: {
                    max: 'dataMax',
                    axisLabel: {
                        fontSize: 11, fontWeight: 'lighter', color: this.isDarkMode ? '#e5e7eb' : '#6B7280',
                        formatter: (value) => value === 0 ? '' : number_format_short(value),
                    },
                },
                yAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    show: false,
                    boundaryGap: true,
                    splitLine: {
                        show: false,
                        lineStyle: {
                            width: 2,
                            type: "solid",
                        }
                    },
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        realtimeSort: false,
                        name: 'X',
                        type: 'bar',
                        barWidth: 6,
                        barGap: 20,
                        barCategoryGap: 20,
                        color: 'rgba(227, 63, 125, 1)',
                        data: config.data.length === 0 ? [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] : config.data,
                        label: {
                            show: true,
                            color: 'rgba(227, 63, 125, 1)',
                            fontSize: 14,
                            position: 'outsideleft',
                            offset: [2, -19],
                            formatter: function (params) {
                                return params.data ? params.data.label.value + ': ' + number_format_short(params.value) : '';
                            },
                        },
                    }
                ],
                dataZoom: [
                    {
                        type: 'inside',
                        yAxisIndex: 0,
                        start: 0,
                        end: (4 / config.data.length) * 100,
                        zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
                        moveOnMouseMove: true,
                        moveOnMouseWheel: true,
                    }
                ],
                legend:
                    {
                        show: false
                    },

            };
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no reference to `getBaseAxis` in your code; are you using any libraries that call that?

Comment: Yes I am using echarts @mykaf

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't contain `getBaseAxis` anywhere. There's no way to know what it calling that from what you have shown